# Syncfusion TreeView doesnt show data

Tags: asp.net, ejs, syncfusion

I have a list that matches the requirements that I get through the request from js.

Data from the request comes filled in, but the list is not displayed

```
< ejs-treeview id="treedata" created="created">
< e-treeview-fields dataSource="@Model.Items" id="LevelCode" parentId="ParentLevelCode" text="Name"                hasChildren="HasChild"></e-treeview-fields>
< /ejs-treeview>


    function created()
    {
        getCategories();
    }


    function getCategories() {
        let treedata = document.getElementById('treedata').ej2_instances[0];
        let request = new ej.base.Ajax(`/Category/GetAll`, 'GET');
        request.send();
        request.onSuccess = data => {
            if (treedata.element !== undefined) {
                let final = JSON.parse(data);
                treedata.fields.dataSource = final.Categories;
                treedata.dataBind();
                treedata.refresh();
            }
        };
    }



    public class GetAllCategoriesHandlerResponseItem
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool HasChild { get; set; }
        public string LevelCode { get; set; }
        public string ParentLevelCode { get; set; }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In TreeView component, the fields property has been provided to set or get the data source and other data-related information. You can use this property to dynamically change the TreeView component data source. But you need to specify the properties in its predefined structure to update the TreeView data source.

Check the below code snippet.

```
  function getCategories() {
    let treedata = document.getElementById('treedata').ej2_instances[0];
    let request = new ej.base.Ajax(`/Category/GetAll`, 'GET');
    request.send();
    request.onSuccess = data => {
        if (treedata.element !== undefined) {
            let final = JSON.parse(data);
            treedata.fields = {datasource: final.Categories, id:"LevelCode", parentId:"ParentLevelCode", text:"Name", hasChildren:"HasChild" };
            treedata.dataBind();
            treedata.refresh();
        }
    };
  }
```

You can refer to the below link to know about the details.

https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/10135/how-to-refresh-the-data-in-ej2-treeview